Как правильно добавить зависимость spring-aspects в приложение на Spring Boot?
Использую jdk 21, Spring Boot 3.3.3. Создаю проект с помощью Spring Initializr:

Помимо Spring Web и Lombok добавляю зависимости Spring Boot Actuator и Prometheus, так как хочу собирать метрики и потом отправлять их в Prometheus и отрисовывать в Grafana (Prometheus и Grafana поднял в Докере). POM-файл выглядит так:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

В коде своего мини-проекта создал такой метод:
    @Timed("taxi_scheduler")
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 30_000)
    public void updatePrice() {
        taxiService.getPrice();
    }

Как я понял, у библиотеки Micrometer есть аннотация @Timed, которая нужна, чтобы узнать время выполнения метода. Её можно навешивать на public-методы. Для её работы необходимо создать бин TimedAspect. Для этого создаю конфигурационный класс с этим бином:
@Configuration
public class TimedConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return new TimedAspect(meterRegistry);
    }
}

Запускаю программу, и вижу ошибку из-за данного конфигурационного класса:
2024-09-16T12:44:28.245+07:00 ERROR 6947 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'timedAspect' defined in class path resource [com/example/unpretending_example_metrics/metrics_02_taxi/TimedConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect]: Factory method 'timedAspect' threw exception with message: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]

    ...
    
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
    at com.example.unpretending_example_metrics.UnpretendingExampleMetricsApplication.main(UnpretendingExampleMetricsApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect]: Factory method 'timedAspect' threw exception with message: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint
    at io.micrometer.core.aop.TimedAspect.<clinit>(TimedAspect.java:87) ~[micrometer-core-1.13.3.jar:1.13.3]
    at com.example.unpretending_example_metrics.metrics_02_taxi.TimedConfiguration.timedAspect(TimedConfiguration.java:17) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.unpretending_example_metrics.metrics_02_taxi.TimedConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$timedAspect$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    
    ...
    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted


Пытался погуглить эту проблему, и вроде бы нашёл решение, а именно: чтобы решить эту проблему советуют объявить зависимость spring-aspects. Так и делаю: добавляю в POM-файл зависимость:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.13</version>
        </dependency>

и теперь приложение запустилось, и метрика @Timed("taxi_scheduler") отображается в Prometheus и Grafana.
Вопрос такой: как правильно добавить зависимость spring-aspects? Сейчас раздел с зависимостями выглядит так:
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Без этой зависимости ошибка -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.13</version> <!-- тут явно указываю версию !!!!  -->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

Выглядит немного коряво, так как мы в зависимостях Спринг Бута не указываем обычно версии библиотек: Спринг Бут сам берёт нужные ему версии вроде бы.
Тогда я попробовал добавить эту зависимость там же, в Spring Initializr. Но тут проблема: он не находит такой зависимости ни по слову aspects, ни по aop, никак:

В общем, подскажите, как правильно добавить зависимость spring-aspects в мой проект на Spring Boot ?

Так и не указывайте версию, если вам не нужна какая-то конкретная версия, а та, что указана в dependencyManagement в spring-framework-bom (при указанном parent pom).
